# GCM Messages not being received sometime

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Friend, I am working with a chat application. In my chat application I am using GCM for push notification. GCM is working fine with my application. But not all time I am not able to get GCM message. Sometime I receive GCM message and sometime don't. Why so? I searched for GCM message failure but did not find the right one.

Anyone, can please help me?

Comment: Do you check the results send by GCM if you are getting any errors ? Please paste the code where you verify the results sent by GCM

Comment: yes @pgratton i check gcm result there is no error i am getting.

Answer (score 7):

When you post a message to the Google GCM server (at https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send), you need to pass three values: registration_id, collapse_key, and data.message.  The collapse_key is likely your issue here.

Make sure that you pass a unique collapse_key for each message that needs to be reliably delivered.  If you use the same collapse_key for each message, then GCM might drop multiple messages that are sent at around the same time.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html.

Comment: String postdata= "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=2419200&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + message + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceToken + ""........This is what I am sending, is it okay. Bcoz I am also facing same problem. Sometime some of the device are not receiving

Comment: Append an incrementing number to your "score_update" collapse key, and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Also I got a reply from someone to make  delay_while_idle=0. Is it required or not.

Comment: That will help to improve the delivery performance, but it shouldn't affect reliability.

Comment: If the device was offline when the push message has been send from the server. According to the documentation, it should receive all pending notifications when it is online again. But I am not receiving in this case. While I am getting when it is active or locked/asleep. What might be the reason.

Comment: I encounter similar problem. For the "collapse_key" issue, now it shows "com.projectname"; From the above discussion, should i add more data behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give much information about your situation and don't share code snippet it is hard to analyze the problem.But, as it is described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html), GCM makes no guarantees about delivery or the order of messages.

Comment: i migrate from C2DM to GCM.i test my app thoroughly actually working fine.How much chance of GCM for sending message.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any calculation about chance of getting message.It depends on Google.

Comment: Other than GCM you can use some services such as (urbanairship,netmera etc.) but they are also using similar technologies as GCM. Or you can implement your server-side and pull from the client but this will be more dificult to handle every situation. And as a suggestion, using push service for chat application is not a good choice.

Comment: Actually my app is livechat application.So,i need a service that push message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your mobile internet through any firewall like "Cyberoam" or something like that then it restricts ports for the GCM push notification .Try to implement it using Direct internet connection without any firewall. This Solved Probelem for me. I hope it will help you too.

GCM requires port number 5228, 5229, and 5230 to be open. GCM typically uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230 that might be restricted by the firewall.